# Is this inequality argument using series valid?

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

In this question I'm proving Bernoulli's inequality on an interval, but I am more interested in how I proved it rather than what I proved.

> Bernoulli's inequality: $(1+x)^a\le1+ax$ for $|x|\le1, 0<a<1$

$$(1+x)^a=1+ax+\frac{a(a-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)}{3!}x^3+...$$

We interpret this as a generating function for a sequence $u_{n}=\frac{a-n}{n} u_{n-1}, u_0=1$

And
$$|\frac{u_n}{u_{n-1}}|=|(\frac{a}{n}-1)|$$

Noticing the numbers are decreasing in magnitude($\frac{a}{n}<1$) and are alternating in sign, I define $R_n=u_{2n}x^{2n}+u_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\le0$ because $|x|\le1$ and the even sequence items turn out to be the negative ones.

$$(1+x)^a=1+ax+R_0+R_1+...$$
$$(1+x)^a\le 1+ax$$

Is this approach to proving the inequality valid? It felt very plausible, but I'm not too sure how it fairs in the infinite series case. It feels as if I could have said the same thing to argue the opposite, taking $Q_n=u_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+u_{2n}x^{2n}$

Comment: Yes, what you have works. More generally, for an alternating sequence $ \sum (-1)^i u_i$, where $ u_i $ are non-increasing terms, we can truncate the initial terms and use that as a upper/lower bound. We do not need to be concerned about convergence issues (IE Magnitude of the limit of the ratio could be 1), and the inequality still applies.